# How can I animate an element programmaticaly using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking at this code http://codepen.io/optyler/pen/FgDyr and if you hover to the triangle element, you will see the animation. However instead of hovering it, I want to do it programmaticaly using JavaScript. This is what I have done so far:

```
document.querySelector('.triangle').classList.add('animateSpeak');
```

and added a new css class

```
.animateSpeak {
    animation: vibrate .5s infinite ease-out;
}
```

The animation is working though as you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLhAD.jpg the left part is only animating. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a CSS 3 animation, you would probably need some sort of `active` class.

Just change the `:hover` selectors (line 54) to, say, `.active` instead. i.e.:

```
.triangle.active,
.triangle.active:before,
.triangle.active:after {
  animation: vibrate .5s infinite ease-out;
}
```

You can start the animation programmatically by adding the `.active` class or stop it be removing the class.

To answer your second question, it looks like the `:before` and `:after` elements need the animation too.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS add

```
.animateSpeak,
.animateSpeak:before,
.animateSpeak:after {
  animation: vibrate .5s infinite ease-out;
}
```

Just a quick thought, you can avoid the intersection of the three becoming darker than their constituents by changing the color from `rgba` to `rgb` or a solid color,

```
$font_color: rgb(231,236,241);
```